# Wrapping content children in a dynamic parent tag with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

**What I want to do**

I want to create a reusable Angular 2 button component that may render as an `<a />` tag or an `<input />` tag depending on an input to the component called `type`. I want the button component to accept content children which will be rendered as the button label.

To illustrate: an Angular template that invokes my `button` component like so:`<button>Hello</button>` should render as `<a>Hello</a>` in the DOM. However, if a property `type="submit"` is set (e.g. `<button type="submit>Hello</button>`) then the output in the DOM should be `<input type="submit">Hello</input>`.

To further clarify, if I were using React I could create [an overly simplified version of] this component with:

```
const Button = ({ type, children }) =>
  type === "submit"
    ? <input type="submit">{children}</input>
    : <a>{children}</a>
```

**Where I'm stuck**

Creating an Angular component that displays content children using `<ng-content />` was relatively straightforward. However, I'm yet unable to render those children inside a *dynamically chosen tag* - either `<a />` or `<input />` depending on the value of the `type` property.

**What I've tried**

I initially tried to use `<ng-content />` inside an `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` directive, only to find out that `<ng-content />` can appear at most *once* in any given template (unless it’s qualified with a selector). However, I want to output *all* content children so selectors are not helpful.

I keep finding references to DynamicComponentLoader, but that appears to be deprecated.

I've seen the [ContentChildren](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html) decorator which would allow my button component to access the content children being passed to it, but I'm not sure how to then take those children and inject them into my component template.

I came across [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html), which seems like it might help me switch between two entirely different templates (one w/ the `<a />` tag and one with the `<input />` tag). However that's marked as “Experimental” and I’m having trouble understanding the usage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: take a look at this plunker to get an idea on how to create a container component which does the trick for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/wh4VJG?p=preview

Comment: Angular2 doesn't support a component to replace the tag it is applied to, but it can wrap another component and you can use `*ngIf` inside the component to show `<button *ngIf="isButton"...` or `<input *ngIf="!isButton"...`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer makes sense, but then is there any way to pass content children through to those lower-order components?

Comment: Sure. You can access content children using `@ContentChildren(...)` See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Comment: I may be missing something totally obvious (new to Angular), but if I understand that correctly `@ContentChildren` just allows me to query the children passed to the higher-order component (see the "What I've tried" section of my Q). It doesn't allow me to inject (transclude?) those children back into a specific location in the template or pass them to another component.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'adapting-button',
  template: `
      <a *ngIf="type !== "submit">{{value}}</a>
      <input *ngIf="type === "submit" type="submit" [value]="value">
  `,
})
export class AdaptingButtonComponent {
  @Input() type: any;
  @Input() value: any;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: `
    <adapting-button [type]="'submit'" [value]="Hello"></adapting-button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this solves the issue I'm having with content children. I can still only output the children via `<ng-content />` in one of the containers.

Comment: I've given it a face-lift. See if it's making any sense. (I can not make use of <ng-content>, switched to a input instead.)

Comment: It looks like that I shouldn't have brought in <ng-container>.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! This is probably my fault for not being clear, but it's essential that the component accept content children (not just a value prop). I'll update the Q.